# Manim: Add mutiple objects with always_redraw

Tags: python, animation, manim

I want to add multiple VMobjects via always_redraw with a loop, but only 1 object appears in the scene.

Is there a fix or other workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Return a VGroup with all objects inside. Example:

```
def draw_collection():
  return VGroup(
    Circle(color=WHITE, radius=0.5),
    MathTex(r"...")
  )
collection = always_redraw(draw_collection)
```

Note that in python you can always define function inside another function